# Encrypting data in des ecb

Tags: c++, openssl

I want to encrypt data from input stream and write them, I am not sure if this is the correct way?

For example I am not sure about this line: `in_encrypt.read((char *)pt, BLOCK_SIZE);` if I am reading last time before eof is reached it might be shorter than 8 and so failbit will be set but I will encrypt data of length 8.

Is it somehow possible to get the length of data that I did actually read from the stream? If so I would then be able to encrypt data of exactly that length BLOCK_SIZE = 8?

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, EVP_des_ecb(), key, NULL);

while(!in_encrypt.eof())
{
    in_encrypt.read((char *)pt, BLOCK_SIZE);
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, ct, &tmpLength, pt, BLOCK_SIZE);
    out_encrypt.write((char *)ct, tmpLength);
}

EVP_EncryptFinal(&ctx, ct, &tmpLength);
out_encrypt.write((char *)ct, tmpLength);
```

Comment: ECB mode provides confidentiality only, its only useful for one block of data (not multiple blocks like an arbitrarily sized file), and you must add a MAC to use ECB mode safely. You should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: I know this is not usable in practice its just a school work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) page, call `in_encrypt.gcount()`.